# How to solve 'src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBodyInternals.h: In function 「void ZeroInitialize(T&) [with T = btSoftBody::Node]」'?

Tags: ros, bullet, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use ubuntu 11.10 and fuerte.

When I rosmake my PCL project, it shows:

```
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/sam_pcl/wei_pcl_tutorial$ rosmake
  [ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                                                                                                                                                    
  [ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building ['wei_pcl_tutorial']                                                                                                                                                   
  [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['wei_pcl_tutorial']                                                                                                                                                           
  [ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120810-175832                                                                                                                             
  [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['wei_pcl_tutorial'] to:
  ['wei_pcl_tutorial']                                                                                                                                            
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                         
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs                                                                                                                                                 
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                    
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs                                                                                                                                       
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                      
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs                                                                                                                                           
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                              
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl  No Makefile in package pcl                                                                                                                                                           
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                          
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                                                                                                                                                   
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                           
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                                                                                                                                                     
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                           
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbag  No Makefile in package rosbag                                                                                                                                                     
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                         
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild                                                                                                                                                 
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                           
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib                                                                                                                                                     
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                       
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole                                                                                                                                             
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                        
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib                                                                                                                                                
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                            
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                                                                                                                                                       
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> bond [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                             
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond                                                                                                                                                          
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                           
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib                                                                                                                                                      
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                          
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp                                                                                                                                                    
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                          
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet                                                                                                                                                    
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                  
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters                                                                                                                                   
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                       
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosservice  No Makefile in package rosservice                                                                                                                                             
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                                                                                                                                                              
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure                                                                                                                            
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]                                                                                                                                                              
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools                                                                                                                            
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                          
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest                                                                                                                                                   
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                           
  [ rosmake ] Last 40 linesllet: 3.3 sec ]                                                                                                                                                [ 1 Active 21/28 Complete ]
  {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBodyInternals.h: In function 「void ZeroInitialize(T&) [with T = btSoftBody::Node]」:
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBody.cpp:80:19:   instantiated from here
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBodyInternals.h:175:17: 錯誤： 未初始化的常數 「zerodummy」 [-fpermissive]
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBody.h:193:9: 附註： 「const struct btSoftBody::Node」 has no user-provided default constructor
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBodyInternals.h: In function 「void ZeroInitialize(T&) [with T = btSoftBody::Material]」:
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBody.cpp:157:21:   instantiated from here
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBodyInternals.h:175:17: 錯誤： 未初始化的常數 「zerodummy」 [-fpermissive]
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBody.h:179:9: 附註： 「const struct btSoftBody::Material」 has no user-provided default constructor
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBodyInternals.h: In function 「void ZeroInitialize(T&) [with T = btSoftBody::Note]」:
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBody.cpp:172:18:   instantiated from here
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBodyInternals.h:175:17: 錯誤： 未初始化的常數 「zerodummy」 [-fpermissive]
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBody.h:267:9: 附註： 「const struct btSoftBody::Note」 has no user-provided default constructor
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBodyInternals.h: In function 「void ZeroInitialize(T&) [with T = btSoftBody::Link]」:
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBody.cpp:243:20:   instantiated from here
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBodyInternals.h:175:17: 錯誤： 未初始化的常數 「zerodummy」 [-fpermissive]
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBody.h:206:9: 附註： 「const struct btSoftBody::Link」 has no user-provided default constructor
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBodyInternals.h: In function 「void ZeroInitialize(T&) [with T = btSoftBody::Face]」:
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBody.cpp:280:20:   instantiated from here
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBodyInternals.h:175:17: 錯誤： 未初始化的常數 「zerodummy」 [-fpermissive]
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBody.h:217:9: 附註： 「const struct btSoftBody::Face」 has no user-provided default constructor
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBodyInternals.h: In function 「void ZeroInitialize(T&) [with T = btSoftBody::Tetra]」:
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBody.cpp:315:20:   instantiated from here
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBodyInternals.h:175:17: 錯誤： 未初始化的常數 「zerodummy」 [-fpermissive]
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn/src/BulletSoftBody/btSoftBody.h:225:9: 附註： 「const struct btSoftBody::Tetra」 has no user-provided default constructor
    make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn'
    make[5]: *** [src/BulletSoftBody/CMakeFiles/BulletSoftBody.dir/btSoftBody.o] Error 1
    make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn'
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet/build/bullet_svn'
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/eigen/bullet'
    make[4]: *** [src/BulletSoftBody/CMakeFiles/BulletSoftBody.dir/all] Error 2
    make[3]: *** [src/BulletSoftBody/CMakeFiles/BulletSoftBody.dir/rule] Error 2
    make[2]: *** [BulletSoftBody] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [installed] Error 2
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (message):
      Build of Bullet failed
    
    
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
  [ rosmake ] Output from build of package bullet written to:
  [ rosmake ]    /home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120810-175832/bullet/build_output.log                                                           
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< bullet [FAIL] [ 3.40 seconds ]                                                                                                                                                            
  [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package bullet. 
  [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                                                                                          
  [ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                                                                                               
  [ rosmake ] Built 22 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                                                                                                     
  [ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                                                                                            
  [ rosmake ] /home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120810-175832                                                                                                                                                  
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/sam_pcl/wei_pcl_tutorial$
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41093/how-to-solve-%27src/bulletsoftbody/btsoftbodyinternals.h:-in-function-%E3%80%8Cvoid-zeroinitialize(t&)-%5Bwith-t-=-btsoftbody::node%5D%E3%80%8D%27?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Something seems to be messed up with your ros workspace. Why does it try to compile bullet at all? It should be installed by the debian package `ros-fuerte-bullet`. Try cleaning up your ros workspace and get rid of the directory `bullet` and its parent `eigen`.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-10**:
What is clean up,get rid of bullet and eigen means? What should I do? Thank you~

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-10**:
You have a directory `eigen` in `/home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/sam_recognition/`. I believe it should not be there. In fuerte there is no package `eigen` anymore. Also, there is a subdirectory `bullet` in `eigen` that should definitely not be there.